# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-router, state

In my parent component, I'm loading data from a json file and using it to set state. Using react-router, I then pass the state down to a child component which renders the data in a route. This behavior works as expected. However, when I attempt to refresh the route, the parent component's state (and the child component's props) are lost, and the page throws an undefined error.

I've attempted to call the data loading functions from the parent component in the `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle method of the child component, but the app throws the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.setState is not a function`.

The parent component code:

```
async loadWorldData() {
 await axios.get("../factbook.json")
    .then(res => {
      let Data = res && res.data.countries;
      Data = Object.values(Data).map(country => country.data) || [];
      let newData = this.removeNull(Object.values(Data));

      this.setState({ worldData: newData})
    });
}
```

The child component code:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.props.loadWorldData();
}
```

I don't know another way to reload the app state without calling the parent function in the lifecycle methods of the child.

Comment: You don't have to use `promises` when you are using `async await`

Comment: You can't do `setState` in componentWillMount. Please move the code to `componentDidMount`

Comment: Also you don't need async await, since you are updating the state on success of it and I don't see a point to block the rendering like this. If your rendering is completely dependent on this API then either fetch it before navigating to this screen or display a loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: This is probably a binding issue.

```
 loadWorldData = async() => {

 const res = await axios.get("../factbook.json")
 let data = res && res.data.countries;
 data = Object.values(Data).map(country => country.data) || [];
 let newData = this.removeNull(Object.values(Data));
 this.setState({ worldData: newData });

}
```

**Why is this not working?**

In order to use setState, you must have access to `this`. Normal functions are **not** bound to `this`. There are two options to fix this issue:

**First: Bind the function to this inside the constructor.**

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.loadWorldData = this.loadWorldData.bind(this);
   }
}
```

**Second: Fat Arrow functions:**

Since Fat arrow functions are bound to `this`, you don't have to worry about binding them inside the `constructor` as denoted by the first example.

Comment: Ahh that works. I had tried to do `const loadWorldData = async() => ... ` but the const was not allowed. Thanks!

Comment: Mark the answer as the correct one if this helped you :)

Comment: There shouldn't be any bind issue because componentWillMount is being written as arrow function.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure on that. I guess the issue is setState inside componentWillMount which doesn't cause rendering. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: This is a child component, the state is being set inside the parent component through a function passed as a prop. ComponentWillMount() wouldn't have worked if it were the child's state.

Comment: Although yes, all API calls must be made in `componentDidMount()`, as for your current reasoning you are little off the point. @MilindAgrawal

Comment: Oops I clubbed two things, my bad. I am actually suggesting to move this code to parent component. If not then yes your answer will fix the error but rendering won't happen because of componentWillMount

Answer (score 0):

```
          async loadWorldData() {
           const self = this;
           await axios.get("../factbook.json")
            .then(res => {
               let Data = res && res.data.countries;
                 Data = Object.values(Data).map(country => country.data) || 
                                 [];
                  let newData = this.removeNull(Object.values(Data));

                  self.setState({ worldData: newData})
                 });
           }
```

you can delete async await you don't need them .